# Manage CPU utilization on Core Data fetch requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, performance, core-data, memory-management

My app is based on search process. I have 36 fields and the fields are switch types, slider types and dropdownlist types. On every selection, I need to update other field values also. In this case, I am executing 36 fetch requests.

Because of this, the app is slow and the CPU utilization goes from 90% to 100%.

How to solve this CPU usage?

Comment: Show your code and model contents

Comment: Maybe you need to move something in background, in addition you could split your view into several views. Like a logical flow step. As @Wain suggested show details...

Comment: 36 fetch requests is a lot of work no matter how you code it. But it's impossible to make more specific comments without knowing more about your app. Why are you doing so many fetch requests over and over? What's going on in the app?

Comment: If you are doing 36 fetch requests to update 36 fields you are doing something wrong.